# Erro ao executar nova Drawable Animation no Android Stuido

Tags: android, animação, drawable

Estou com um problema. Criei uma animação teste para uma Splash Screen de um projeto meu. Ela funciona de boa. Agora quando fiz uma nova animação para subtituir essa antiga, o aplicativo para do nada.

Animação 1 => animation.xml, animation_01.png, animation_02.png, ... animation_06.png.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**xml correspondente =>**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_01" android:duration="500"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_02" android:duration="500"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_03" android:duration="500"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_04" android:duration="500"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_05" android:duration="500"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_06" android:duration="600"></item>

</animation-list>
```

Animação 02 => an.xml, an01.png, an02.png, ... an18.png.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**xml correspondente =>**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an01" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an02" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an03" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an04" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an05" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an06" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an07" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an08" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an09" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an10" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an11" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an12" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an13" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an14" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an15" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an16" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an17" android:duration="150"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an18" android:duration="500"></item>

</animation-list>
```

Aqui o código da activity SplashScreen com a primeira animação que dá certo.

```js
package genesysgeneration.crushhelper;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView ivInvisible;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Thread myThread = new Thread(){

            @Override

            public void run(){

                try {

                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                    finish();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        };

        myThread.start();

        ivInvisible=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivInvisible);
        ivInvisible.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);

        AnimationDrawable animation_01 = (AnimationDrawable)ivInvisible.getBackground();
        animation_01.start();

    }

}
```

Para trocar de animação eu mudo a linha `ivInvisible.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);` para `ivInvisible.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.an);`. **Nenhum erro é acusado, porém quando executo na máquina virtual do android o aplicativo para do nada.**